# How to get all users in one organization unit using Google Directory API using vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api

In the Google Directory API, I cannot find a method to get all users in a specific organization unit of Google Apps. Is it possible? And how? Based on the Google Directory API document, programmers can get all the organization units, or all the users for the whole domain, but there is no description on how to get users of one organization unit. This feature is crucial important to construct the organizations/users hierarchical tree. Please help, thanks.

I have tried to look into the documentation but wasn`t able to solve the problem.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { decodeCredential } from 'vue3-google-login'
// Assuming you have a method to initialize Google API client and check authentication

const isLoggedIn = ref(false)
const userProfile = ref(null)
const accessToken = ref(null) // Add this line to declare accessToken
const usersList = ref([]) // For storing the list of users

const callback = (response) => {
  const userData = decodeCredential(response.credential)
  console.log("Handle the userData", userData)
  userProfile.value = userData
  isLoggedIn.value = true
  accessToken.value = userData.accessToken // Store the access token here
}

// Method to fetch users from an OU
async function fetchUsersFromOU() {
  try {
    const orgUnitPath = encodeURIComponent('/zepoapp'); // Replace with your actual OU path
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&fields=nextPageToken,users(orgUnitPath,primaryEmail)&orgUnitPath=${orgUnitPath}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.value}` // Use the stored access token
      }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.users) {
      usersList.value = data.users;
    } else {
      // Handle no users or error in response
      console.error('No users found or error in response:', data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
  }
}



// Add this function to handle the button click
const newAction = () => {
  fetchUsersFromOU();
}
</script>

<template>
  <GoogleLogin v-if="!isLoggedIn" :callback="callback" prompt auto-login/>
  <img v-if="isLoggedIn" :src="userProfile.picture" alt="User Profile" />
  <button v-if="isLoggedIn" @click="newAction">Descargar usuarios</button>
  <div v-if="usersList.length">
    <h2>Users in OU:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="user in usersList" :key="user.id">{{ user.primaryEmail }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.